# What is the javascript command to change the table top row (heading) cell tags from td to <th class="filter">

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a function that dynamically creates a table as follows

```
function createDisplayTable(rn,cn)
{
for(var r=0;r<parseInt(rn,10);r++)
{
var x=displayTable.insertRow(r);
for(var c=0;c<parseInt(cn,10);c++)  
{
var y=  x.insertCell(c);
}
}
}
```

However, in order to use a JQuery/bootstrap module, I need to change the top row (heading) cell tags from `td` to `<th class="filter">`
What is the Javascript code that will make the change?

Comment: When you create the table make the first row a header row.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith if you're just asking how to replace one element with another.

Comment: sorry, but I am a novice. Can anyone give me the actual line of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp3= displayTable.rows[0].outerHTML;
var temp= temp3.replace(/<td>/g,'<th class="filter">');
var temp1="</td>";
temp= temp.replace(/temp1/g,'</th>');
temp= temp.replace("<tr>","<thead><tr>");
temp= temp.replace("</tr>","</tr></thead><tbody>");
var temp2= displayTable.outerHTML;
temp2=temp2.replace(temp3,temp);
temp2=temp2.replace("<tbody>","");
displayTable.outerHTML=temp2;
```